# What happens when two processes both call register() at the same time

Tags: parallel-processing, erlang

What happens when two different processes that run in parallel both call at the same microsecond (whatever the smallest unit the CPU has)

```
register(proc, spawn( ... ) )
```

Does this register two processes on the same atom?

If the answer to the above question is yes then looking at the following code:

```
start(Atom, Fun) when is_atom(Atom), is_function(Fun, 0) ->
Sender = self(),
Fun2 = fun() ->
       case catch register(Atom, self()) of
           true ->
           Sender ! {started, self()},
           Fun();
           _ ->
           Sender ! {already_running, self()}
       end
   end,
Pid = spawn(Fun2),
receive
{started, Pid} ->
    {ok, Pid};
{already_running, Pid} ->
    already_running
end.
```

If two processes call the above code at the same time will both receive 
`{Ok, Pid}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Only one process can be registered with a given name (atom).** The second process to call `register/2` will be unsuccessful and will raise a `badarg` error.

As for what happens when both processes call `register/2` simultaneously, I imagine Erlang has a table of registered processes kept in memory. When `register/2` is called the table is locked, and the new process is registered. If two processes call `register/2` at the same time, one would have to wait until the other process completed the `register/2` call. Once registry lock is released the second process would be able to register, but the name would already be in the registry, so the call would raise a `badarg` error. I haven't looked at the implementation of this function, but I imagine it works something like this.

In any case, **you will never have two processes registered under the same name. Registration is atomic. One register call will succeed and one will fail.**

More information is available here:

- http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#register-2
- http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#id84713

Comment: The table will be locked by one of the two processes. If two are calling it at the same time (same microsecond) then how would erlang know which process to let register first? I understand that you would never have two processes registered under the same name. My question is in regards to how Erlang deals with the case in which `register` is called at the very exact time by two processes

Comment: I don't know. I haven't ever dug that far down in the Erlang source code. I do know that is an implementation detail. You should never rely on the order of registration. Just like message passing. If two process send a message to a third process, there no guarantee that the messages will arrive in a set order. These are implementation details that should never be relied on in application code. Sorry I am not able to provide more insight.

Comment: Just as a final note. I mainly asked the previous question because the code which I've took from another Stack Overflow question(see the post) is supposed to always guarantee one process to fail and one to succeed. The way I see this is only and only if the register() locks that table. This way one process waits for the `catch register(a,b)` to finish. Hence there is no way the register from both process is run at the same time

Comment: The `register` call is a BIF, and yes, everything is locked such that only a single process can enter it at a time. If you have two processes calling it at the exact same time to register using the same name, only one acquires the locks and proceeds, and the other waits and then eventually proceeds only to fail with `badarg`.

Comment: @SteveVinoski what's the need for a start() function then? If the register() will lock and never let two processes enter it at the same time. Why would I need a start() func? Is this simply so that we can throw the error we want? Instead of letting the program crash we simply return a tuple? Is this it?

Comment: Due to a lack of context I can't answer why your specific example needs a `start` function, but the ultimate idea is that you start a new process so it can provide a service, and you register it to allow clients of the service to find it so they can interact with it and make use of what it offers. Starting and registering such processes is the basis for all Erlang/OTP behaviors such as `gen_server` and `gen_fsm`.